# The empty set as an atomic unit

Tags: set-theory

I was reading some perspectives on the empty set in ZFC set theory.  To my understanding, every other set that we can explicitly show to exist is made up of the empty set and sets of the empty set.  So I was wondering if the following is an appropriate way of looking at the universe of sets.

Any object in set theory is a set.  In other words, we can take an object and "unwrap" it to look at the contents.  But each object is the culmination of all of its contents into a singular unit, a set.  So we can think of sets as both collections and singular points.  And we can move downward in a set, choosing an element, unwrapping it, and then choosing an element of that set.    Eventually, If I'm not mistaken, we will reach the empty set (this is philosophical, I don't know if you can actaully complete this process within the system of ZFC).   The empty set is a singular unit (or set) that has no elements.  So would it be wrong to think of the empty set as the unique atom of set theory? It is a set with no contents, but it is also a unit in which we cannot move further downward into.

This could be similar to the prime numbers in algebra.  They are atomic units of the natural numbers.  And by the fundamental theorem of algebra, every natural number has a unique prime representation.  So every number is a the product of a unique set of atoms.

Comment: You're perfectly right. ZFC only deals with "pure" sets; that is, sets whose elements are sets. The axiom of foundation shows that if you have any set you can drill down through the elements of its elements of its elements ... only finitely many times before stopping at the empty set. The von Neumann universe shows how to explicitly build up the universe of well-founded sets from the empty set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe

Comment: You are only half right. It is true that the axioms of ZFC only assert existence of the empty sets and set-theoretic constructs built from it. But they *do not* assert that no other sets exist (nor can they, in first order logic).  Von Neumann's set universe V that you describe is only one model of ZFC, there are other models, [non-well-founded ones](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/663763/152568). We get closer with [second order ZFC](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213020/152568).

Comment: See [Set theory with *urelements* (aka: atoms)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Urelements_in_set_theory)

Comment: @Conifold Which part of "The von Neumann universe shows how to explicitly build up the universe of well-founded sets .,.." was unclear? Didn't my wording specifically anticipate your objection?

Comment: @user4894 AF is first order, and so it can not show what you suggest. There is a difference between well-foundedness as seen from inside and outside a model.